# Is it possible to play a .wax file in Mac Os X?

Tags: mac, audio, file-format, file-conversion

I'm trying to build a listening quiz for some of my students and I found a great site with lots of possible activities for them.  But the files are in .wax format.  Is there any way I can get these files to play on my Mac?  Or is there some converter I can use to convert them to plain old mp3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flip4Mac](http://www.telestream.net/flip4mac-wmv/overview.htm) is a plugin for QuickTime.

According to [this pdf](http://www.telestream.net/pdfs/technical/Flip4Mac-ASX-Support.pdf) it supports the .wax file format.

Also a .wax file is actually a metafile which points to the actual media file that needs to be played so you cannot convert the file directly. For more information on this have a [look here](http://all-streaming-media.com/faq/streaming-media/Metafiles-WAX-Windows-Media-audio-redirector.htm).